# How to integrate admob in phonegap android app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, admob

I am developing android app using phonegap and try to integrate admob into my coding. The problem is "The ad is not displayed in index page." I am using admobpro plugin. Kindly help me. Here is index.html coding (admob script is directed added to index page not separate js)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mycss.css" />
    <script src="css/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>

var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        interstitial: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    };
}

if(( /(ipad|iphone|ipod|android|windows phone)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) )) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', initApp, false);
    window.alert("arun here")
} else {
    initApp();
}

function initApp() {
    if (! AdMob ) { alert( 'admob plugin not ready' ); return; }

    AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: admobid.banner, 
        isTesting: true,
        overlap: false, 
        offsetTopBar: false, 
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        bgColor: 'black'
    } );

    AdMob.prepareInterstitial({
        adId: admobid.interstitial,
        autoShow: true
    });
}

</script>


<div data-role="page" id="quest">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" class="links_home">

        <!--<h1>links</h1> -->
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Ans1">This Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Ans2">This Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Ans3">This Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Ans4">This Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Ans5">This Link 5</a></li>

       </ul> 

    </div><!-- /content -->


    <!--<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div> /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

cordova.js is the cordova bridge between javascript and native code, if missing it, the plugins won't be called.

You forget to add cordova.js in your index.html.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

See example index.html here:

- https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-game-phaser/blob/master/demo/index.html

You can directly copy this admob.js to your project, and reference in index.html:

- https://github.com/floatinghotpot/admob-demo-game-phaser/blob/master/demo/js/admob.js

Comment: thanks for your comment. i followed your second url (referenced admob.js to index.html). Its working for normal html page. it does not work for  jquery mobile multi page template. please suggest me an idea to do this